# C#&MatLab: Do I need MCR to run the MWArray.dll in any computer?

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, visual-studio-2012

I am using some MatLab functions in c# as dll. These functions need MWArray and I should add it as reference to my project but when I try to run the program on another computer that does not have MCR (MatLab Compiler Runtime) it gives some error. Should I install MCR to run this program on different computers? If yes, is there anyway to run program without MCR?

Answer (score 0):

There's not really much to say:

1. Yes
2. No

:)

Comment: So there is no opportunity to convert a matlab function to dll. That is silly component.

Comment: "If the target machine does not have the version 8.1 of the MCR installed, and the end users are unable to download the MCR using the above link, include MCRInstaller.exe."
Also i have found this. I am not happy -.- :D